# How to preserve string with newlines passing from LWC to VF controller for PDF rendering

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, controller, javascript-controller

I have a *Lightning Web Component* (LWC) which takes a text input from the user. The text input is entered via a `lightning-textarea`, i.e. can also contain text with newlines.

The LWC contains an iframe which refers to a Visualforce (VF) Page, which is rendered as a PDF. The URL of the iframe reference `pdfUrl` is generated in the LWC, containing the text input `textValue` of the user as GET parameter. The URL is encoded using the javascript function [encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) before passing it to the VF controller.

The VF page takes the text input, and renders it in the PDF.

This process works great apart from the fact, that potential newlines in the user's input in the `lightning-textarea` are not preserved. I tried different solutions mentioned on the web but couldn't make it work, hence the dedicated question:

**How can I preserve newlines when passing a LWC text input to a VF controller for PDF rendering.**

---

## Minimum working example (MWE)

### LWC HTML markup

Defining 2-column LWC design with the input `lightning-textarea` and the `iframe` to preview the PDF

mWEPdfNewLine.html

```html
<template>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <lightning-textarea
        label='My text input'
        value={textValue}
        onchange={handleTextInputChange}>
      </lightning-textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <iframe class='pdf-preview' src={pdfUrl}></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### LWC Javascript controller

Passes the `pdfUrl`.
The non-encoded `pdfUrl` with a two line input is displayed in the developer console in the browser as:

```
/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?textValue=foo and bar and  double space
foobar
```

The encoded `pdfUrl` (which is actually passed) is shown as (`%20` for a space character and `%0A` for the new line feed)

```
/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?textValue=foo%20and%20bar%20and%20%20double%20space%0Afoobar
```

mWEPdfNewLine.js

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class mWEPdfNewLine extends LightningElement {     

  @track textValue = 'foo and bar and  double space';
  @track pdfUrl = '/apex/MWEPdfNewLine';

  renderedCallback() {
    this.updatePdfUrl();
  }

  handleTextInputChange(event) {
    this.textValue = event.target.value;
  }

  updatePdfUrl() {
    var pdfUrl = '/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?textValue='+this.textValue;
    console.log(pdfUrl);
    var encodedPdfUrl = encodeURI(pdfUrl);
    console.log(encodedPdfUrl);
    this.pdfUrl = encodedPdfUrl;
  }
}
```

### Apex controller

Retrieves the `textValue` as GET parameter.

MWEPdfNewLine.cls

```java
public with sharing class MWEPdfNewLine {
    public String textValue {get; set;}
    
    public MWEPdfNewLine() {
        Map<String, String> parameters = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        if(parameters.get('textValue') != null) this.textValue = parameters.get('textValue');
    }
}
```

### Visualforce page

Renders the PDF output, testing different output solutions. Also using the [white-space: pre-line](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.php) CSS property, which should help to wrap on newlines, but unfortunately doesn't.

MWEPdfNewLine.page

```html
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MWEPdfNewLine" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <!-- Following style supposed to preserve new lines while collapsing multiple spaces, but has no helping effect -->
        <style>
            .preserve {
                white-space: pre-line;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="preserve">
            <i>Direct output:</i><br/>{!textValue}
        </p>

        <p class="preserve">
            <i>outputText:</i><br/><apex:outputText styleClass="preserve" value="{!textValue}" />
        </p>

        <p class="preserve">
            <i>outputText (escape=False):</i><br/><apex:outputText styleClass="preserve" value="{!textValue}" escape="false" /> 
        </p>
        <!--
            No option, can only be used with Sobjects, not with custom variables
            <i>outputField:</i><br/><apex:outputField value="{!textValue}" />
        </p>
        -->
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

#### Output

All teste solutions neglect the newline and simply concat both lines without a space. Having a single space in the text is shown correctly and also multiple spaces are properly collapsed to a single space.

Tested with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers.

[image: Output]

Comment: It's a shame I can only upvote this question once. Very well written, and great job showing your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final visual force URL needs to be defined explicitly to ensure proper handling of newlines. This can be done using the [DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm#apex_System_DomainCreator_getVisualforceHostname) apex class function.

**Big shoutout and thanks to @sfdcfox for his amazing support effort.**

---

## Issue

In the Javascript controller I define the URL for the PDF/Visualforce page to be shown in the *iframe* with `/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?<parameters>`.

The following `textValue` is used as example with a newline and two spaces between line1 elements.

```
line1a  line1b
line2
```

This results in Salesforce/the browser completing the URL to `https://<my-domain>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?textValue=line1a%20%20line1b%0Aline2` with the encoded `textValue` with `%20` for spaces and `%0A` for the new line.

The URL is forwarded automatically to `https://<my-domain>--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/MWEPdfNewLine?textValue=line1a++line1bline2` i.e. replacing all `%20` with `+` and dropping all `%0A`, hence neglecting newlines.

This is also related to the usage of [enhanced domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_url_format_changes_enable_enhanced.htm&type=5) in Salesforce.

## Solution

My solution is to define the Visualforce domain `https://<my-domain>--c.sandbox.vf.force.com` excplicitly. To have a dynamic solution depending on domain name and production/sandbox environment one can use the [DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm#apex_System_DomainCreator_getVisualforceHostname) apex class function, which returns exactly this domain.

## Updated minimum working example (MWE)

### LWC HTML markup

(not changed)

mWEPdfNewLine.html

```html
<template>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <lightning-textarea
        label='My text input'
        value={textValue}
        onchange={handleTextInputChange}>
      </lightning-textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
      <iframe class='pdf-preview' src={pdfUrl}></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### LWC Javascript controller

Added a *@wired* function `getVisualForceDomain()` to retrieve the visualforce domain from the apex controller.

Note: I added some handling in the `renderedCallback()` function ensure the `visualForceDomain` parameter is set before loading the PDF. This is not fulfilled on the first call of `renderedCallback()` automatically called by the browser. Once the text input is changed this is called again and the parameter is available. Since I do some initialization in my actual code, waiting for other input, this behaviour is fine for me. Pleae consider checking this.

mWEPdfNewLine.js

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getVFOrigin  from '@salesforce/apex/MWEPdfNewLine.getVFOrigin';

export default class mWEPdfNewLine extends LightningElement {    
    
  static get VISUALFORCE_PAGE_URL() {return '/apex/MWEPdfNewLine'};

  @track textValue = 'line1a  line1b';
  @track pdfUrl = '';
  @track visualForceDomain = null;

  renderedCallback() {
    if(this.visualForceDomain == null) return;
    this.updatePdfUrl();
  }

  handleTextInputChange(event) {
    this.textValue = event.target.value;
  }

  updatePdfUrl() {    
    var pdfUrl = this.visualForceDomain; // https://<my-domain>--c.sandbox.vf.force.com
    pdfUrl += mWEPdfNewLine.VISUALFORCE_PAGE_URL;
    pdfUrl += '?textValue='+this.textValue;

    var encodedPdfUrl = encodeURI(pdfUrl);
    this.pdfUrl = encodedPdfUrl;
  }

  @wire(getVFOrigin)
  getVisualForceDomain({error, data}){
    this.visualForceDomain = data;
  }
}
```

### Apex controller

Added the *@AuraEnabled* function `getVFOrigin()` to call the [DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm#apex_System_DomainCreator_getVisualforceHostname) apex function to retrieve the proper Visualforce Domain.

Note: The `getVisualforceHostname()` expects a parameter *packageName*. Since I am using an unmanaged package, I am passing the value *null*. See [DomainCreator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm) documentation for more information.

MWEPdfNewLine.cls

```java
public with sharing class MWEPdfNewLine {
  public String textValue {get; set;}
    
  public MWEPdfNewLine() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
      if(parameters.get('textValue') != null) this.textValue = parameters.get('textValue');
  }

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static String getVFOrigin() {
    String packageName = null; // no managed package is used, hence pass null
    String visualForceHostname = 'https://' + DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname(packageName);
    return visualForceHostname;
  }
}
```

### Visualforce page

(simplified)

MWEPdfNewLine.page

```html
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MWEPdfNewLine" applyBodyTag="false">
  <head>
    <!-- Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks -->
    <style>            
      .preserve {
        white-space: pre-line;                
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="preserve">{!textValue}</p>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

#### Output

Solutions works, tested with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the encoding, it's the rendering. I duplicated your problem with a simple test:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <head>
        <style>
            .preserve {
            white-space: pre-line;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="preserve">
            This is a test.
            This is another.
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

The fix is to emit your own HTML. The following code renders correctly:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="preserveSpaceController" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .preserve {
                white-space: pre-line;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="preserve">
                {!message}
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

```
public class preserveSpaceController {
    public String message { get; set; }
    public preserveSpaceController() {
        message = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('message');
    }
}
```

Edited to demonstrate URL parameters working well.

```
/apex/preserveSpace?message=line1%0aline2
```

Output:

[image: Demonstration of example code from the earlier code blocks]

Comment: Thanks for your support. I changed my apex page settings from `<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MWEPdfNewLine" applyBodyTag="false">` to `<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MWEPdfNewLine" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" docType="html-5.0">` but the behaviour persists, no newlines in my output... Even if I render it as HTML with just `<apex:page controller="MWEPdfNewLine">` Any other ideas?

Comment: @HeXor You need to also add the `<html>` tag, as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: I can confirm if I run your `apex:page` snippet, it renders correctly with 2 lines. But adding my controller `<apex:page [...] controller="MWEPdfNewLine" [...]>` and replacing the explicit text with my `{!textValue}` variable again does not properly render the newlines. Any idea what an apex controller does with a text input containing `%0A` for newlines in the `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('textValue')`? If I print this with `System.Debug()` it already shows the compacted string, no `%0A` contained anymore in the debug console output.

Comment: @HeXor I updated this to include a URL parameter, and a screenshot of the output. It might be helpful if you edit your original question to include the latest version of the code.

Comment: Thanks for updating this helps alot. I tried to reproduce your result. Which URL prefix are you adding before the `/apex`? If I use `https://<my-domain>.sandbox.lightning.force.com/apex/preserveSpace?message=line1a%20line1b%0aline2` (which I assume is being used by the iframe) it forwards to `https://<my-domain>--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/preserveSpace?message=line1a+line1bline2` replacing all `%20` with a `+` and simply drops all `%0A`, hence no new line. If I access `https://<my-domain>--c.sandbox.vf.force/apex/preserveSpace?message=line1a%20line1b%0aline2` directly it works fine.

Comment: I think I found a solution, gonna post the answer.